# Ehcache and Callback

Tags: message-queue, ehcache

After registering a listener in Ehcache, one can get callback into the listener implementation. If system/VM crashes after making an entry in the ehcache and before the call back is made, will the ehcache make this call back on recovery/restart.

Answer (score 1):

We did some research and found that we can implement a messageQueue with Ehcahce. For persistence we can configure and ehcahce.xml to do the same. Once the process is successful, we can evict the cache. Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ehcache is not a persistent message queue.